# What is the arithmetic mean of all integral solutions to $|x−2|>|2x+1|$?

Tags: inequality

I'm learning Solving Inequalities and encountered this problem. I understand that to solve this problem, I need to consider these four situations: $x-2>0$, $x-2<0$, $2x+1>0$, and $2x+1<0$. But it turns out to be very complicated. I wonder whether I'm on right track.

> What is the arithmetic mean of all integral solutions to $|x-2|>|2x+1|$?

Comment: Hint: $(x-2)^2 \gt (2x+1)^2$ has *very* few integer solutions.

Comment: Doing all the casework is complicated, but you can bypass the algebra if you take a geometric approach. Remember that $|a-b|$ is the distance between $a$ and $b$. Factoring out the 2 of the right side of your inequality, we get $|x-2|>2|x+1/2|$. This is saying the distance of $x$ from $2$ is more than twice the distance of $x$ from $-1/2$. This means $x$ is lower than $1/3$ but more than $-3$. (Draw a picture if necessary.)